# Trying to ask more questions

Tags: discussion, comments

When I am looking at a question, which I could possibly have a solution but I don't understand the question properly.I try to ask more questions but I am not able to comment as I don't have have 50 rep points and I have to answer the questions, which means it gets down voted or flagged. This is really annoying. Why do we need 50 rep points, just to comment?